# How to do a multi select like the one shown in the picture using HTML and JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

Below is an example of what I want: A multi select (kind of like a text) field, which if press on drops down with options to choose from. Chosen option becomes disabled from the dropdown and inserted into the field.

[image]

Comment: Please review https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple This Demo can be useful. If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I know about autocomplete, I am asking about the field itself, with the highlighting, with the expansion when you click on the input field, with the selected inputs as boxes, everything included in this example.
I am asking for guidance because I don't know where to start. Autocomplete does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo at
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/

and code at
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/jquery.dropdown.js

that looks like exactly what you want.